Get entity field as entity from another table
I'm working on a PostgreSQL function in SQL Editor in Supabase to fetch data in my Swift app.
I have Place entity with category: PlaceCategory
+-----------------------------------+
|               Place               |
+-----------------------------------+
| id: String                        |
| name: String                      |
| imageUrl: String                  |
| description: String?              |
| url: String?                      |
| infoSource: String?               |
| address: String?                  |
| rating: Double?                   |
| price: Double?                    |
| category: PlaceCategory           |
| promotion: Bool                   |
| teamChoose: Bool                  |
| lat: Double?                      |
| lon: Double?                      |
| distance: Double?                 |
| isActive: Bool                    |
| photosArray: [String]?            |
| city: String                      |
| keyWords: String?                 |
+-----------------------------------+

+-----------------------------------+
|           PlaceCategory           |
+-----------------------------------+
| id: String                        |
| name: String                      |
| systemIcon: String                |
| isActive: Bool                    |
+-----------------------------------+

Now I have a function that fetches only Place, when category is String(text). And it is working fine, but for more convenient using results of fetching in my app I wanted to change this function to fetch data as Place but with category as PlaceCategory
Is there any opportunity to change my function to correctly fetch Places with category as PlaceCategory entity?
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_places_for_city(
    exceptions_param text[],
    categories_param text[],
    price_categories_param text[],
    divisor_param text,
    city_param text
)
RETURNS SETOF public.places AS $test$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        public.places AS place
    WHERE
        place.category = ANY(categories_param)
        AND place.id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(exceptions_param))
        AND place."isActive" IS TRUE
        AND place.city = city_param
        AND (place.price is null OR
        (CASE
            WHEN place.price = 0 THEN 'Free'
            WHEN place.price <= 1500 THEN '$' 
            WHEN place.price <= 3000 THEN '$$'
            ELSE '$$$' 
        END) IN (SELECT unnest(price_categories_param)))
    ORDER BY md5(place.id || divisor_param) ASC
    LIMIT 10;
END;
$test$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

